# TwitterAPIExchange call fails

Tags: php, twitter

This is an code for an app to retrieve data from twitter users. I'm using TwitterAPIExchange api library.  The call fails, returning boolean `false` instead - `var_dump($string)` prints `bool(false)`.

Also I can't figure out why when I run the code I'm not getting any retrieved data i.e the output is blank.

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $user = "lestaaaaaaa";
}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $count = $_GET['count'];
} else {
    $count = 20;
}

$getfield = "?screen_name=".$user."&count=".$count;
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
var_dump($string);

if (is_array($string))
{
    foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
}
print_r($string);

?>
```

Comment: Because in certain place of your script it is type of `boolean` with value `false`

Comment: okay so why ain't my code retrieving any user data?

Comment: Does performRequest() return `false` if it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline

```
Returns the 20 most recent mentions (tweets containing a users's @screen_name) for the authenticating user.
```

So you need not pass screen_name as a parameter while performing this request. It will take the authenticating user's screen name by default.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code

```
/** URL for REST request, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/ **/
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user']))  {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
} else {
        $user  = "lestaaaaaaa";
}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $user = $_GET['count'];
} else {
    $count = 20;
}

$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter  ->setGetfield($getfield)
                                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                                ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {
    echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";
    exit();
}
foreach($string as $items){

        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
```